# JWT token is expiring before the given expire time

Tags: c#, jwt

I am using

```
var payload = new JwtPayload(issuer, audience, claim identities, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), DateTime.Now);
```

to generate auth token having 60-minute expiring time but it is expiring before the expiring time

Comment: Please try https://jwt.io/ to decode the generated JWT. Is there the correct time shown?

More insights, like an example token or the exact time it is valid, would help alot.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to build a token in my asp.net core web api service:

```
private string BuildToken()
{
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtOptions.Key));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
      _jwtOptions.Issuer, // some issuer, e.x. you can specify your localhost
      _jwtOptions.Issuer,
      expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_jwtOptions.Expires),  // int value
      signingCredentials: creds);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

Perhaps this helps you somehow.

Comment: token are generating but my problem is that it is expiring before the given exp time. Did you face the same issue?

Comment: No, I didn't. The token is expired exactly after the given time.

Comment: Thanks mate. let me check and try to use your code may be it works.